# ASP.NET TextBox TextMode set to Date not working in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" />
```

It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE 11.  Googling around isn't yielding a lot of helpful answers.  As far as I know, IE 11 is HTML5 compliant.

Answer (score 2):

The `TextMode` property generally corresponds to the `<input type="" />`  attribute (excepting `multiline` which renders a `<textarea />`). ASP.NET 4.x introduced additional values corresponding to new HTML5 input types.

Internet Explorer 11 does not support most of these new input types, specifically it does not currently support the "`date`", "`datetime`", nor "`time`" values. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime however Chrome, Opera, and Mobile Safari currently do.

Comment: So let me get this right.  4.5 was released in 2012, but Microsoft's own browser still does not work with its own products?

Comment: @user79284 pretty much :) I cannot excuse IE's delay, but I understand the motivation was to support mobile devices (Windows Phone supports date-input), I also note that the W3C specification for HTML5 forms still isn't really finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to accomplish this. On top of the page add these references and script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({
            changeYear: true,  //Recently added
            changeMonth: true  //Recently added
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Then apply these properties to the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_desired_id" runat="server" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" autocomplete="off" MaxLength="10" class="date" />
```

I have also tested it placing the textbox within a gridview and a repeater and works perfectly in IE 11.

EDIT: In the code of the function, I have included some handy features which allow the user to go faster and pick up the month and the year, in case it has to go much further in the past.

Comment: Does this code work for all the major browsers also (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) ?

Comment: Yes, the above solution was tested on these web browsers as well.