# asp Textbox Textmode date not in Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I'm new to asp.net, I'm trying to let the user put in a date using textmode="date",

in the browser I only see an empty textbox. I'm using ASP.Net 4.5 and a firefox browser version 51.0.1 (64-bits)

It doen't show the date textmode.

My code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="startDateBox" runat="server"  TextMode="Date"/>
```

Is there something wrong with this code or can it not be done in my browser?

EDIT:
Right now I am on Firefox version: 61.0.1
Not sure since what version but asp date textmode works now on firefox.

Comment: This looks like a well known bug with FireFox and IE browser. They have problem in supporting this. This works very well with Google Chrome but FireFox and IE are not suitable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774816/asp-net-textbox-textmode-set-to-date-not-working-in-ie-11 and https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/776764/Introducing-Textmode-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Then I will try it an other way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chetan commented, it is because FireFox and IE do not support this feature. It does work on Google Chrome.

To see what is and isn't supported check the article below and scroll down to **History**.

[Here the article with more explanation](http://codeproject.com/Tips/776764/Introducing-Textmode-in-ASP-NET)